# echo record to be deleted

Tags: php, html, mysql

so i'm trying to echo all the fields of a record to be deleted from the index.php

I can't seem to get the data relating to the record.

Here's my code

This is the index.php where the record is deleted.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","project1");
// Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
          {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
          }
// Query sites table for all records      
$result_sites = mysqli_query($con,"select * from sites");
?>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site.css">
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function checkDelete()
    {
        return confirm('Confirm delete?');
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Site Code Page</h1>
    <p>this website is used to add site codes, search sites codes and delete sites codes</p>
        <h2 class="button"><a href=/index.php>Home</a></h2>
        <h2 class="button"><a href=/insert.php>add site</a></h2> 
        <h2 class="button"><a href=/>search site</a></h2>
<div class="sites_table">
    <?php
        // Draw table of all records within sites table
        echo '<table border="1">
        <tr>
        <th>Site Name</th>
        <th>Site Code</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Postal Code</th>
        <th>Province</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Delete Record</th>
        <th>Modify Record</th>
        </tr>';
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_sites))
            {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['site_name'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['site_code'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['site_address'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['site_city'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['site_postalcode'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['id_province'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['id_country'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td><a href="/delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '" onclick="return checkDelete()">delete</a></td>';
                echo '<td><a href="/modify.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">modify</a></td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }           
        echo '</table>';
    ?>
</div>
<div class="page_number">
Page ->,    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the Delete.php file

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","project1");
        // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

//Delete Site record from the Sites table   
$sites_id=$_GET['id']; 
    if (isset($_GET['id']))
    { 
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM sites WHERE ID='$sites_id'");

    echo 'id: ' . $id . ' site_name: ' . $site_name;
    }
?>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: `$id` and `$site_name` don't exist. How could you ever expect it to work?

Comment: was expecting it to be passed along with the side_id

Comment: How? By magic? Go and get those values from the database *before* deleting the record. It's that simple.

Comment: You're doing `$sites_id=$_GET['id']` before checking `if(isset($_GET['id']))`.

Comment: I'm already collecting the data in the index.php. would I append those fields to this line?  echo '<td><a href="/delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '" onclick="return checkDelete()">delete</a></td>';then the GET would have it in the URL?

Comment: You could do that, too. Saves you a trip to the database.

Comment: Please learn how to use parameterized queries. Now you could face SQL injection problems. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work